# Create a red faq-moderator tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderation, meta

Moderators are being encouraged to document their processes, tools, and guidelines on meta.  While we could merely tag everything [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) I suspect that it would be better to have a special [faq-moderator](/questions/tagged/faq-moderator) tag that can only be assigned by the meta moderators to keep everything separate but easily searchable.  A user tag would only end up cluttered, so I suggest a nice red tag.

If we have moderator posts that are tagged [faq-moderator](/questions/tagged/faq-moderator) then it makes it easier for new moderators (pro-tems and newly elected mods) to have a specifically searchable tag rather than having to filter through results for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [moderator](/questions/tagged/moderator). The former tags should be found by "normal users" looking for FAQ entries, and the later tag should generally pertain to moderator oriented discussions "who's my moderator", or "look what this moderator did" or "when can I be a moderator" (I'm not insinuating those are great questions, just trying to illustrate "moderator" questions that aren't "faq-moderator" questions.)

Additionally, the more "power users" of MSE would be happy to know more about the moderation process and tools, so this would give them a chance to follow specific tags for clarity and openness. A lot of users know a *lot* about the operation of the Stacks, and so they would have advice to add to the discussion.

There is at present a [moderator-faq](/questions/tagged/moderator-faq) tag, but it's not red yet.

Comment: Isn't [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) already a red moderator tag? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @waiwai: He means [faq-moderator].  I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Good looking out @AdamDavis ;)

Comment: What's wrong with `[faq]` + `[moderation]`?

Comment: I don't see the need: as Jon sais, `faq`+`moderation` seems to fit the bill. Also keep in mind that only trilogy moderators are meta.SO moderators, not the more numerous SE2.0 moderators.

Comment: @Jon Anyone can add [moderation] to a post.  There are already a lot of FAQ posts, and there should be a lot of moderation faq posts.  In this case I believe that having a single tag that can only be added or removed by a meta moderator is going to make is a better option then using the red [faq] and the regular [moderation].

Comment: @Adam: You should add that into the post.  That's a very good point.

Comment: I too don't think this can be covered by `faq + moderation` - searching and filtering won't work properly that way, for example. This needs a specific tag

Comment: @Pekka How does searching not work?

Comment: @Michael: Searching for [faq] only will also get the moderator-faq posts.  They should be mutually-exclusive searches.

Comment: @Robert ...why? [moderator-faq] posts are [faq] posts nonetheless

Comment: @Michael: It's not a huge detail, but c'mon...If I were an ordinary user I wouldn't be the least bit interested in the mod faqs...Well, maybe a *little.*  Conceptually, it's two different books.

Comment: There are over 100 separate user faqs.  A new user trying to figure out what the deal with "closing" shouldn't have to try and figure out which closing [faq] they should read.  Further, it more clearly delineates the distinct differences between high rep users and moderators.  Lastly, while I don't expect users to read every user FAQ, I really would expect new moderators to read every moderator FAQ - but not necessarily every user faq.  Having to sort through them would make one less likely to go to the trouble.

Comment: @Adam The argument only makes sense one way -- it's hard to find posts tagged [faq] but not [moderation]. It's [trivial](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+moderation) to find posts tagged with both